# Google Hangout: Handle visibility from server

Tags: security, google-plus

I am making a game with Google Hangout where I need to control which participant could communicate with others.

I want to be sure that players could not change the list of participant he could see by calling a javascript function. Because from what I understand each participant could change his visibility of other participants, and I want to block that.

So I wonder if it is possible to control the visibility between participants at server-side.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No.

Medium answer: It really depends exactly what you need, but probably not.

Much longer answer:
It sounds like you want finer grained control over both visibility and message sending/state sharing than the Hangout API allows for. The Hangout API reflects what participants can see in the actual hangout today - everyone else who is in the hangout. The shared state is shared with all other members of the hangout running the same app, and the visibility is for all users in the hangout or the same app.

If you want to restrict or limit this (for example, if people are divided into teams and you want a "team chat"), you would need to use your own server to coordinate this communication, on at least some level. Your server would either need to actually do the communication between team members, or distribute a shared secret that each team would use as a cypher for their shared state.

One possible trickier solution might be to have each team run a different app. Since each app only shares state with the same app running on another participants machine, and can list only the other members who are running the same app, this might be a valid solution in some cases.